# Start a launch file via cpp

Tags: roslaunch, rosnode, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys,

is there a way to start a launch file via c++ in a node?

In my case, I have an Actionserver (actionlib) and want to be able to start a few other nodes as a goal. But since these other nodes that I want to start on demand are changed pretty often, I want to store them in a separate file and I thought, a launch file should do the trick.

Any ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/341272/start-a-launch-file-via-cpp/) by [jere](https://answers.ros.org/users/50780/jere/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-01-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-01-09**:
It would seem harsh, but I'm almost inclined to close your post. Reason: there are many Q&As about this exact topic and quite a few of them include usable code.

Could I ask you to first try using Google to search for older Q&As? Append `site:answers.ros.org` to your query. That should return quite some results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Could you try following code?

```
#include <cstdlib>
...
std::system("roslaunch your_package your_node");
```

std::system allow you to pass its arguments to terminal.

---

Originally posted by [harumo11](https://answers.ros.org/users/39186/harumo11/) with karma: 46 on 2020-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lennart](https://answers.ros.org/users/52806/lennart/) on 2020-04-28**:
It worked for me. I've got the same question. Thank you.